# How do I proper create Array Schema in Mongoose and filter by given criteria?

Tags: javascript, arrays, node.js, mongodb

I'm quite newb to mongodb and mongoose, so I ask you to help me.
I've an API, which works and now I want to extend it with filtering for given params.

I've a Order model, which points to two different collections of documents Material & User Schemas and have a quantity element.

```
let Order = new Schema({
    materials: 
    {
        type: Array,
        material: { 
            type: mongoose.Schema.Types.ObjectId,
            ref: 'Material'
        },
        qty: {
            type: Number
        }
    },
    userId: {
        type: Schema.Types.ObjectId,
        ref: 'User'
    }
}, {
    collection: 'orders'
})
```

Also I've method to create an order:

```
  exports.createOrder = (req, res) => {
    if (!req.body.user) {
        res.status(400).send({message: 'Content can not be empty!'});
    }
    const order = new Order({
        materials: req.body.materials,
        userId: req.body.user
    });
    order
    .save(order)
    .then(data => {
        res.send(data);
    })
    .catch(err => {
        res.status(500).send({
          message:
            err.message || "Some error occurred while creating the Order."
        });
      });
   }
```

If I create Order filling only Material ID, it creates and filtering by given material ID in filter request.

post request

[image: post request]

filter request

[image]

But If I trying to point qty it isn't present in response.

post request with qty
[image]

filter request ending with previous document id

[image]

There is my question: How can I create Order exact way I need (Material ID and qty number must persist) and How can I perform a filtering operations on them?

Any help appriciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

My mistake was in method how I create order as well as I make a filtering request.

Correct method to create order with data storing in array type is following

```
exports.createOrder = (req, res) => {
    if (!req.body.user) {
        res.status(400).send({message: 'Content can not be empty!'});
    }
    const order = new Order({
        materials: {material: req.body.materials, qty: req.body.qty},
        userId: req.body.user
    });
    order
    .save(order)
    .then(data => {
        res.send(data);
    })
    .catch(err => {
        res.status(500).send({
          message:
            err.message || "Some error occurred while creating the Order."
        });
      });
}
```

as you can see, difference is how I form materials array.

next thing is in filter request

```
exports.filterOrder = (req, res) => {
  Order.find({"materials.material": req.body.material})
  .then(data => {
    console.log(data);
    res.send(data);
  })
  .catch(err => {
    res.status(500).send({
      message:
        err.message || "Some error occurred while retrieving Orders."
    });
  });
}
```

If I need to filter orders contain necessary material I need to place subelement of array in quotes with dot notation. This will work also with "material.qty" parameter if needed.